# Boost program options - pass arg name from function result

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I've reproduced my problem based on the example from [the official tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html).

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;
using namespace std;

const char* withAlias(const char* name, const char* alias)
{
    return (string(name) + "," + alias).c_str();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    po::options_description desc;
    const auto name = withAlias("compression", "c");
    desc.add_options()
        (name, po::value<int>(), "compression bla bla"); // this doesn't work
        ("compression,c", po::value<int>(), "asdasdasd"); // this works

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("compression"))
        cout << "Compression set to " << vm["compression"].as<int>() << endl;
    else
        cout << "Compression not set" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run my program: `my_bin --compression 5`, it throws an error, stating:
`unrecognized option '--compression'`.

When I don't use an alias at all (aka `("compression", ...)`), this works as expected.

It happens when there's a `,` in the name string, but only when it's passed not as a string literal.

Can't really figure out what's causing this.

Comment: Did you try `"-c,--compression"`? (read now the link, probably won't work)

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie just did, didn't work, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char* withAlias(const char* name, const char* alias)
{
    return (string(name) + "," + alias).c_str();
}
```

Your string pointer is invalidated when the `std::string` object is destroyed.

You need to keep the `std::string` around, like so:

```
std::string withAlias(std::string name, std::string name)
{
    return name + "," + alias;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    po::options_description desc;
    auto name = withAlias("compression", "c");

    desc.add_options()
      (name.c_str(), po::value<int>(), "compression bla bla");
    ...
```

Comment: Isn't the `const char*` copied?

Comment: I tried changing the signature to `std::string withAlias` and `.c_str()`ing the call to it, still fails.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait, yes, but that's just a pointer. The underlying data is a different matter.

Comment: So how would you suggest keeping it alive?

Comment: @GioraGuttsait You need the std::string object itself to live long enough for boost to read the data. c_str() ing the result still has the same problem, since it's a temporary.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait Updated my answer with an example

Comment: Thank you so much @Frank, updated my code (both the sample code, but the wrapper i'm trying to build), and it is certainly what you pointed out. Thank you dude! Have a good day!